# Execute an external service outside a docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins, glassfish

I have a glassfish server in a linux machine and a docker container that run jenkins. I want to execute some glassfish commands but from the docker it seems that glassfish is not up. The message that I get is:

```
Remote server does not listen for requests on [localhost:4848]. Is the server up?
```

Glassfish is running in linux on port 8080 and admin on 4848. The way I have run docker for jenkins is:

```
docker run --rm -d --name jenkins \
        --expose 4848 \
        -v /opt/glassfish3:/opt/glassfish3 \
        -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker \
        -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime -v /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone \
        -v $GF/libs:$JH/libs \
        -p 8081:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

Although glassfish is up, jenkins doesn't see it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Can you put glassfish server into another container?

Comment: Probably yes...but I have to install it from the beginning. Currently this is how it works. I suppose if I put it into another container due to docker.sock I will be able to handle it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker` creates by default a [bridged network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) therefore Glassfish and Jenkins are on different network segments.

From the message you get it seems that the command tries to connect to Glassfish on `localhost`. What you need instead is to connect to the `IP` address of the linux machine (which I assume is the host). 
Run on the host the `ip` command (or `ifconfig`) to get the IP address:

```
ip addr show docker0
```

(`docker0` is the ethernet bridge device created by `docker`)

By default Glassfish listens on 0.0.0.0 (all network interfaces) so it should listen on docker0 as well. Then run `asadmin` with the `--host` option (the machine name where the domain administration server is running). For example:

```
asadmin --host <ip of linux machine> list-applications
```

The default network interface can be used as well in place of `docker0`.

In alternative you could run the jenkins container in [host mode](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/). In host mode it shares the network interfaces with the host so it will be able to connect to `localhost`.

Hope that helps